# Using If trying to get a vector a certain length

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I'm  trying to use if function to create a vector `X` that follows the pattern of the if statement, that is length 5. However, when I print `X`, I get 5 vectors with length 1. How do I fix this

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  if (i <2){
     a<-i
  }
  else {
    a<-(i-1)
  }
  X<-a
  print(X)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R overwrites the contents of your variables `a` and `X` with each loop.  To avoid this, you can make `X` a list, and put your value in a different position with each loop.

```
X <- list()
a <- list()
for(i in 1:5) {
    if(i<2){
        a <- i
    } else {
        a <- i-1
    }
X[i] <- a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your final plan is to create a vector, you may initialize a vector ("X") first, and then add a value ("a") in each 'for' loop.

```
X = vector("numeric",0)
for (i in 1:5){
  if (i<2){
    a <- i
   }
   else{
    a <- (i-1)
   }
   X = c(X, a)
   print(X)
}

X
# [1] 1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Creating object like this is not recommended. http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf 2nd Circle of R Inferno.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for providing the link.